# Logging not outputing anything

Tags: c#, logging

I am trying to use logging for a c# console project. Every resource online seems to be for asp.net and using `appsettings.json` which is something that my project doesn't seem to have so I expect it is something asp.net related. I found a video using the following example for logging.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleTesting;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
                                          {
                                              builder.AddConsole();
                                          });

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger");

        logger.LogCritical("Critical");
        logger.LogDebug("Debug");
        logger.LogInformation("Information");


        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

But this doesn't print anything in the console apart from `Hello World`.

Comment: What version are you using, there are differences. I'm going to assume the newest which I believe is 3.0. FWIW [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/logging-nonaspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0) this.

Comment: On the nuget package manager it says 7.0.0 preview , although im not sure if this is the correct information you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is one of timing/buffering. If you just add a `Thread.Sleep(5000);` to the end, I suspect you'll see all the output. (I do on my computer.)

Of course, you don't want to add a `Thread.Sleep` call to your real code - you really want to flush all the loggers.

By experimentation, it looks like disposing of the `LoggerFactory` does the right thing. In your simple example, you can do that just by changing the declaration into a `using` statement:

```cs
using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
```

The `LoggerFactory` will be disposed at the end of the method, which at least *seems* to flush the logger. I don't yet have documentation to back this up as the right way of doing things though.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work , although , i would expect the output `Hello World` to come after the log messages , but the other way around seems to occur , is this fixable , meaning , can i output the log messages first and then the `Hello World!`?

Comment: @Ledrake: Well you could dispose of the logger factory *before* calling `Console.WriteLine` :) Seriously, I suspect the ConsoleLogger is buffering whereas Console.WriteLine isn't. You *may* be able to configure ConsoleLogger not to buffer.